# Porque al crear una collections,en mongodb por consola y al pedir los datos en nodejs me retorna un arreglo vacio?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

estoy trabajando mongodb, hice una collections de una base de datos por medio de la consola y luego  hice un esquema del mismo tipo de datos y nombre en nodejs

```
const mongoose =  require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const usuarioSchema =  new Schema({
    nombre:{type:String,required:true},
    apellido:{type:String,required:true},
    direccion:{type:String,required:true},
})

let usuarioModel = mongoose.model("usuario",usuarioSchema);
```

y  luego pido los datos de esta manera :

```
usuarioModel.find({}).exec((err,result)=>{
     if(err){
         console.log(err)
     }
     else{
      return res.json(result)
     }
 })
```

pero el resultado final es un arreglo vacio:

```
  []
    ​
    length: 0
    ​
    <prototype>: Array []
```

que estara pasando? ya hice una consulta  de los datos en mongodb por consola y si estan los datos
dentro de ella,si alguien podria apoyar con este problema muchas gracias

Comment: quita el objeto del find `find({})` por `find()`

Comment: me huele a [asincronía](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189365/async-await-in-nodejs-mongoose)

Comment: @Enzon lo hice pero no funciona no me da los datos,muchas gracias por el apoyo

Comment: @ Paulo Urbano Rivera sigo teniendo el problema del retorno de datos :( pero siempre muchas gracias por la informacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se insertan datos en una colección de MongoDB mediante el [shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/). Luego se consulta un modelo de datos de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com) creado a partir de un [Schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) que define los campos del modelo de la misma forma en que fueron insertados en la colección mediante el *shell*.

Sin embargo, al consultar los datos desde Mongoose, mediante el método [`find()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html), el resultado es un `Array` vacío. Siendo que en la base de datos hay datos previamente introducidos desde el shell.

El problema es que el modelo de datos no está apuntando a la misma colección donde fueron almacenados los datos usando el shell.

Mongoose por defecto [pluraliza](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) el nombre de la colección que almacenará los datos del Esquema, basándose en el nombre del modelo.

En tu caso, el modelo de datos en Mongoose se llama `usuarioModel`, por lo tanto Mongoose almacenará esos datos en una colección llamada `usuariomodels` en MongoDB. Y también leerá los datos de esa colección.

Como los datos no fueron almacenados allí, sino que fueron almacenados en la colección llamada `usuarios`, es lógico que Mongoose te de como resultado un Array vacío.

**SOLUCION**

La solución es simple, pero hay que entenderla desde el punto de vista del diseño de la base de datos.

Supongamos que en el *shell* de MongoDB has insertado los datos en una colección llamada `usuarios`. Entonces, al crear tu modelo de datos en Mongoose, debes asegurar que el esquema apunta a la misma colección, de lo contrario Mongoose pluralizará el nombre de la colección basándose en el nombre del modelo.

Para apuntar un esquema de datos a una colección específica, debes pasar un segundo objeto como argumento al constructor del esquema:

```js
const UsuarioSchema = new Schema({
    // campos del esquema
},
{ collection: 'usuarios' }); // <- nombre de la colección en Mongo
```

Como puedes observar el segundo argumento es un objeto que contiene un campo llamado `collection` cuyo valor es el nombre de la colección donde hemos insertado los datos desde el *shell* de MongoDB.

Por último, es una buena práctica nombrar el modelo de datos con letra mayúscula, para tener claro que las referencias de Mongoose se hacen sobre Modelos y no sobre colecciones:

```js
const Usuario = model("Usuario", UsuarioSchema); // <- Nombre del modelo entre comillas va en mayúsculas
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema y te ayude a tener clara la forma de trabajar con datos almacenados previamente en MongoDB

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte es la solución del problema, fue una explicación clara y precisa muy concreta